# How to edit AWS Credentials in terminal?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terminal, command-line-interface

What is the command to edit secret key in `aws configure` in terminal?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just type `aws configure` again (or `aws configure --profile <profile_name>` to edit a specific profile). If you just confirm the suggested value by hitting enter, it will remain unchanged.

---

or

Change just the `aws_secret_access_key` by typing

`$ aws configure set aws_secret_access_key <secret_key>`

---

or

You can edit the AWS credentials directly by editing the AWS credentials file on your hard drive. The `aws_access_key_id` and the `aws_secret_access_key` are stored in the `~/.aws/credentials` file by default. You can use any editor to edit them, such as vim, emacs, or nano, e.g.

```
$ nano ~/.aws/credentials
```

Additionally, you can have credentials for many different AWS accounts in the same credentials file by using profiles. As a result, if you have one `development` account and one `production` account, the content of the file may look like

```
[development]
aws_access_key_id = <key id of dev account>
aws_secret_access_key = <secret access key of dev account>

[production]
aws_access_key_id = <key id of prod account>
aws_secret_access_key = <secret access key of prod account>
```

(naturally, you need to replace `<key id of dev account>`, `<secret access key of dev account>`, etc with the actual IAM credentials for each account respectively)

Ref: [AWS CLI Configuration Variable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/config-vars.html#the-shared-credentials-file)

Answer (score 1):

```
aws configure set aws_secret_access_key <secret_key>
```

[Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/configure/set.html#examples)

Comment: I have the key already set in aws configure, I need to access it again. Is there anyway I can open the configure file in terminal to see the values?