# How do I update my access key id from an old one on AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

My goal is to access my s3 buckets from the command line using my AWS educate account.

I expected to get a list of my s3 buckets in the command prompt. I typed in this command. aws s3 ls

I actually received an error message saying Invalid Access Key ID.
They shown do not match they key on the home age of my AWS educate account.

How do I change the keys listed to match the ones on my AWS Educate home page? I think if I correct this then I will be able to access my s3 buckets with aws cli.

Comment: This is the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53355333/how-to-edit-aws-credentials-in-terminal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run:

```
aws configure
```

And follow the prompts to configure a new Access Key and Secret Access Key.

If this isn't working, there are two other things you can check:

1. Have you set any of the following environment variables? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html. These can override the ones set using `aws configure`
2. If that fails, check that $HOME/.aws/credentials is not write protected, or even try updating the credentials manually.

Comment: When I do this, I see the old key and secret access key.  Even if I enter in the new one. When I try to run the aws s3 ls, I get an InvalidAccessKeyID.

Comment: When you run it again, do you see the old key or the new key? I can think of two possibilities here; either your AWS Credentials file ($HOME/.aws/credentials) is write-protected for some reason and the AWS CLI tool can't save your changes or the new Access keys are also stale - is there some way to validate them?

Comment: Alternately - the format of the credentials file is a simple .ini style text file - so manually entering the details may be an option if for some reason `aws configure` isn't working for you.

Comment: One other possibility is that you've overriden the access key / secret access key via environment variables. If so, either change these variables to the new keys or unset them: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html

Comment: I manually updated the ini file like you suggested. So, now when I run aws s3 ls ...it says An error (InvalidAccessKeyId) occurred when calling the ListBuckets operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.

Comment: Weird - what do you see if you run `aws configure` now?

Comment: I see the right key but it is still not connecting. Maybe, I need to add my session token. Not sure.

Comment: This helped me to answer the question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53355333/how-to-edit-aws-credentials-in-terminal