# Create a '~/.aws/credentials' file on Linux

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, docker

I'm setting up my computer to use Amazon's credential helper for Docker. There a step in which I should add stuff to `~/.aws/credentials`, but I don't even have an idea how to create that `.aws` file or what it means to have a `.` right at the beginning.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Why not create the file?

Comment: Files with a `.` at the start are hidden. You need to copy files into the container, so you need them where your build your containers if you need them to be in the container. If you're hosting on AWS though, you don't need a credentials file.

Comment: The best way to create the credentials file is to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws configure` command. It will ask for details, and will create both the `credentials` and `config` files.

Comment: Install aws-cli. Run aws configure.  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53355333/how-to-edit-aws-credentials-in-terminal][https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html?presearch08f-20]

Answer (score 3):

just use the command `mkdir .aws` to create the `.aws` directory.